# Flag positive/negative pairs where id is the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pairwise

I have a dataset with ~50k rows. There are 2 relevant columns for my problem which are 'Saldo' and 'id'.

I would like to flag pairs (2 rows) were id's match and were Saldo = - Saldo.

NB:

- the dataframe is not sorted (yet) on `id`.
- A single `id` can have multiple pairs (A).
- 1 id can have an odd number rows, for example 3 rows with 2 positive and 1 negative value and absolute values are equal. In this case a +/- pair has to be flagged, not the trio, For example, see the `id="I"` in the data below, where only index `12` and `13` should be flagged.

a data example is:

```python
import pandas as pd
data = {'id': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'H', 'I','I','I'], \
        'Saldo': [-2209.00, -17391.00, 2209.00, -2209.00, 2209.00, -2209.00, -17588.51, -18457.71, -104179.79, -16957.20, 23644.95, -23644.95, -2209.00, 2209.00, -2209.00]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
   id      Saldo
0   A   -2209.00
1   B  -17391.00
2   A    2209.00
3   D   -2209.00
4   A    2209.00
5   A   -2209.00
6   F  -17588.51
7   F  -18457.71
8   F -104179.79
9   G  -16957.20
10  H   23644.95
11  H  -23644.95
12  I   -2209.00
13  I    2209.00
14  I   -2209.00
```

I came up with this code:

```python
for i in range(len(df)-1):
    if df.iloc[i]['Reconciled'] == 'Reconciled': # If row is already Reconciled, skip
        continue
    # Look for matching rows in the remaining rows
    for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
        if (df.iloc[i]['id'] == df.iloc[j]['id'] and
            df.iloc[j]['Reconciled'] == '' and
                df.iloc[i]['Saldo'] == - df.iloc[j]['Saldo']):
            # Mark both rows as reconciled
            df.at[i, 'Reconciled'] = 'Reconciled'
            df.at[j, 'Reconciled'] = 'Reconciled'
            break
```

It works, but it takes more than a day to process my dataset.

I think this process could be sped up by using a good mask or by vectorizing? Was also thinking on sorting and grouping.

The solution would look something like this:

```
   id      Saldo  Reconciled
0   A   -2209.00  Reconciled
1   B  -17391.00
2   A    2209.00  Reconciled
3   D   -2209.00
4   A    2209.00  Reconciled
5   A   -2209.00  Reconciled
6   F  -17588.51
7   F  -18457.71
8   F -104179.79
9   G  -16957.20
10  H   23644.95  Reconciled
11  H  -23644.95  Reconciled
12  I   -2209.00  Reconciled
13  I    2209.00  Reconciled
14  I   -2209.00
```

Here is another attempt I made, but it flags unpaired entries in trios as `Reconciled`

```python
# No good mask, trio bug :(
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    matching_rows = [(df.loc[index:,'id'] == row['id']) & (opbrengst['Saldo'] == -row['Saldo']) \
    & (row['Reconciled']== '')]
```

Comment: What do you want your output to look like?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi: Thanks for asking. I will edit my initial post.

Comment: Please refrain from posting screenshots of text. It is almost always more readable to post the actual text itself, with the correct [formatting](/help/formatting). I've edited your question to replace the screenshot of the desired dataframe with text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to *group* your data by `id`, which should nudge you towards using [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
Since each `id` can have multiple `Saldo` values, you want to also group by the absolute value of `Saldo`.:

```
df["Saldo_abs"] = df["Saldo"].abs()
for k, v in df.groupby(["id", "Saldo_abs"]):
    print(v, end="\n\n")
```

I've truncated the output to show only selected groups

```
  id   Saldo  Saldo_abs
0  A -2209.0     2209.0
2  A  2209.0     2209.0
4  A  2209.0     2209.0
5  A -2209.0     2209.0

  id    Saldo  Saldo_abs
1  B -17391.0    17391.0

...

  id     Saldo  Saldo_abs
6  F -17588.51   17588.51

  id     Saldo  Saldo_abs
7  F -18457.71   18457.71

  id      Saldo  Saldo_abs
8  F -104179.79  104179.79

...
```

Next, you want to separate the positive and negative values in each group, and pair them up:

```
all_pairs = []
df["Saldo_abs"] = df["Saldo"].abs()
for (grp_id, saldo_abs), grp in df.groupby(["id", "Saldo_abs"]):
    saldos = grp["Saldo"]
    grp_pos = saldos[saldos > 0].reset_index() # We don't care about the index when creating the pairs, so reset the index
    grp_neg = saldos[saldos < 0].reset_index()
    pairs = pd.concat((grp_pos, grp_neg), axis=1)
    pairs.columns = ["Index1", "Saldo1", "Index2", "Saldo2"]
    pairs.insert(0, "id", value=grp_id)
    all_pairs.append(pairs)
```

This gives a list of dataframes in `all_pairs`, which you can concatenate into a single dataframe:

```
pd.concat(all_pairs).reset_index(drop=True)
```

which gives:

```
   id  Index1    Saldo1  Index2     Saldo2
0   A     2.0   2209.00       0   -2209.00
1   A     4.0   2209.00       5   -2209.00
2   B     NaN       NaN       1  -17391.00
3   D     NaN       NaN       3   -2209.00
4   F     NaN       NaN       6  -17588.51
5   F     NaN       NaN       7  -18457.71
6   F     NaN       NaN       8 -104179.79
7   G     NaN       NaN       9  -16957.20
8   H    10.0  23644.95      11  -23644.95
9   I    13.0   2209.00      12   -2209.00
10  I     NaN       NaN      14   -2209.00
```

---

After you updated your question with your desired output, it looks like you don't care about the actual pairs, only whether they have a pair. You can change the code in the loop to modify the original dataframe instead of creating a bunch of dataframes in `all_pairs`:

```
df["Saldo_abs"] = df["Saldo"].abs()
for (grp_id, saldo_abs), grp in df.groupby(["id", "Saldo_abs"]):
    saldos = grp["Saldo"]
    grp_pos = saldos[saldos > 0] # We DO care about the original index now, because that's how we know which rows to set as Reconciled
    grp_neg = saldos[saldos < 0] # So don't reset index

    num_pairs = min(len(grp_pos), len(grp_neg))
    # The first `num_pairs` elements from grp_pos and grp_neg are paired
    # So set the flag in the original dataframe
    df.loc[grp_pos.index[:num_pairs], "Reconciled"] = "Reconciled"
    df.loc[grp_neg.index[:num_pairs], "Reconciled"] = "Reconciled"

df.drop("Saldo_abs", axis=1, inplace=True)
df["Reconciled"].fillna("", inplace=True)
```

Which gives your desired:

```
   id      Saldo  Reconciled
0   A   -2209.00  Reconciled
1   B  -17391.00            
2   A    2209.00  Reconciled
3   D   -2209.00            
4   A    2209.00  Reconciled
5   A   -2209.00  Reconciled
6   F  -17588.51            
7   F  -18457.71            
8   F -104179.79            
9   G  -16957.20            
10  H   23644.95  Reconciled
11  H  -23644.95  Reconciled
12  I   -2209.00  Reconciled
13  I    2209.00  Reconciled
14  I   -2209.00
```

---

While this approach still involves iteration, it only loops over the *groups*. Modifying the actual rows of the dataframe is done in a vectorized way, so this method will be faster than iterating over all the rows of your dataframe

Comment: It sure is faster! Minute+ instead of a day+ on my working dataset. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick way to do it.

Logic is (**Edit:** logic is wrong, see comments):

- You want to groupby "id" and the absolute value of "Saldo"
- For each group, of size `n`, each first `N` rows -- where `N` is the biggest even integer below `n` -- can be considered "Reconciled". This is because you can make pairs out of them, but if `n` is odd then there is a single row that is left alone

```py
def all_true_even(n):
    """ Returns all True, except one False at the end if n is odd """
    return [True] * (n - n % 2) + [False] * (n % 2)


df = (
    df.assign(saldo_abs=df["Saldo"].abs())  # tmp col for groupby
    .groupby(by=["id", "saldo_abs"], group_keys=False)
    .apply(lambda df: df.assign(Reconciled=all_true_even(len(df))))
    .drop(columns="saldo_abs")  # remove tmp col
)
```

```
   id      Saldo  Reconciled
0   A   -2209.00        True
1   B  -17391.00       False
2   A    2209.00        True
3   D   -2209.00       False
4   A    2209.00        True
5   A   -2209.00        True
6   F  -17588.51       False
7   F  -18457.71       False
8   F -104179.79       False
9   G  -16957.20       False
10  H   23644.95        True
11  H  -23644.95        True
12  I   -2209.00        True
13  I    2209.00        True
14  I   -2209.00       False
```

Comment: @PieterdeWit is each group guaranteed to have only one unpaired value? Can e.g. id=A contain three positive and one negative values? If so, this answer doesn't work.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi: Yes it can. For example a 'trio id' of A, A, -A Would give me a balance of 2 * A instead of zero. In my situation this would not work. Maybe if you could sort on +/- pairs within a group, this approach might work.

Comment: @PieterdeWit right -- it would work if you counted the number of positive and negative values. The smaller of these counts (`N`) gives the number that are reconciled, and the rest are not. Even if you do this, it is not safe to assume (as paime's answer does) that the first `2*N` values are reconciled and the rest are not, since each group is not necessarily sorted in pairs. Now it comes down to flagging reconciled rows by their index, which is the only reliable way to do so for the general case.